# apache airflow - log format customization options

Tags: python, logging, airflow

I found out that the airflow platform is using the Flask log structure (in the airflow.cfg [core] section)
`log_format = [%%(asctime)s] {%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d} %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s`.

I would like to modify this string and also add the dag id, task id and other "ti" info of the dag.

I tried using the jinja template syntax (i.e. {{ ti.dag_id }}) but that didn't seem to work.
`log_format = [%%(asctime)s]:{{ ti.dag_id }}:{{ ti.task_id }}:{{ ti.run_id }} - %%(log_color)s%%(levelname)s%%(reset)s - %%(log_color)s%%(message)s%%(reset)s`

how can i achieve this?